# Ubuntu 22.04 autoinstall hung?

Tags: boot, server, 22.04

I am pxebooting from a centos box a ubuntu 22.04. the config looks something like this:

```
label 5
menu label ^5) Install Ubuntu 22.04 Server
kernel ubuntu22/vmlinuz
initrd ubuntu22/initrd
append root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 ip=dhcp url=http://192.168.1.14/ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.1.14/kickstart/
```

the meta-data file exist but is empty (chmod 755) and the user-data file looks something like this:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntu-server
    password: "$6$exDY1mhS4KUYCE/2$zmn9ToZwTKLhCw.b4/b.ZRTIZM30JZ4QrOQ2aOXJ8yk96xpcCof0kxKwuX1kqLG/ygbJ1f8wxED22bTL4F46P0"
    username: ubuntu
```

also chmod 755.
when i try to boot, it gets stuck here:
[stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE9JV.png)

I'm trying to boot into a vm with the hardware that meets the minimum system requirements.
Is it stuck or is it actually doing something? Its been at that screen for over 20 minutes. How can I tell

Comment: How much memory does the VM have?  PXE requires more memory because the ISO is downloaded and kept in memory.  I would suggest at least 4GB of RAM.

Comment: it does have 4GB. I will try to increase it to 6GB and see what happens. it has 30GB of hard drive space as well

Comment: @Stan Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem netbooting Ubuntu Server 22.04 from netboot.xyz with an autoinstall file specified. My VM has 4GB of RAM, and 40GB of disk space.

Comment: Increasing the RAM on my virtual machine to 8GB solved the hanging issue - I also gave it a second vCPU/core, but I'm assuming the RAM is what solved it.

My autoinstall file (basic example from Ubuntu website) was ignored, however, and I just ended up going through the setup wizard manually. But I'm guessing that's a different issue. Oh well....